# Detection Text from natural images

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, ocr, conv-neural-network

I write a code in **tensorflow** by using **convolution neural network** to **detect** the text from images. I used TFRecords file to read the street view text dataset, then, I resized the images to **128** for height and width.

I used 9-**conv layer** with **zero padding** and three ***max_pool layer with window size of (2×2) and stride of 2***. Since I use just three pooling layer, the last layer shape will be (16×16). the last conv layer has **'256' filters**.

I used too, two **regression fully connected layers** (tf.nn.sigmoid) and tf.losses.mean_squared_error as a loss function.

My question is
is this architecture enough for detection process?? I know there is something call ***NMS*** for detection. Also what is the label in this case??

Comment: Did you read smt about Neural nets ? it's just not possible to answer your question! that actualy the reason why this is called machine learning ! [ I didn't down vote it ]

you may want to check :https://github.com/georgesung/ssd_tensorflow_traffic_sign_detection

Comment: I know that my question is not good, but I am new in computer vision. I will check this tutorial, thank you

Comment: Please ask pure machine learning questions on [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Unless they are specifically about programming, these questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I think you are right, thank for these two website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general and this not a rule , it's just based on my experience, you should start with a smaller net 2 or 3 conv layer, and say what happens, if you get some good result focus more on the winning topology and adapt the hyperparameters ( learnrat, batchsize and so one ) , if you don't get good result at all go deep meaning add conv layer. and evaluate again. 12 conv is really huge , your problem complexity should be huge too ! otherwise you wil reach a good accuracy but waste a lot computer power and time for nothing ! and by the way use pyramid form meaning start wider and finish tiny

Comment: Thank you I will take your advice

Comment: here is a good and clear version to start :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585234/strange-values-of-training-and-testing-when-running-my-cnn-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment78174591_45585234