# Dataset input from bmp images only 50% accurate

Tags: tensorflow

I've created this graph to try:

1. Import BMP files and generate label based on their filename (L/R).
2. Train a network to determine between the left and right eye.
3. Evaluate the network.

I'm using the new framework and get it all in as a dataset. The code runs, but I only get 50% accuracy (no learning happening).

Can anyone check that the graph is right and it's just my network I need to fix ?

```
""" Routine for processing Eye Image dataset
    determines left/right eye
    Using Tensorflow API v1.3
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import fnmatch
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import nnLayers as nnLayer

IMAGE_SIZE = 460
SCALE_SIZE = 100
NUM_CLASSES = 2
IMAGE_DEPTH = 3

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
# Basic model parameters.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 200,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', 1001,
                            """Number of images to process in a batch.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_directory', './eyeImages',
                            """directory of images to process.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('test_directory', './eyeTest',
                            """directory of images to process.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('log_dir', './logs',
                            """logging directory""")
def _parse_function(filename, label):
    """Takes filenames and labels and returns
        one hot labels and image values"""
    #read the file
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    #decode BMP file
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_bmp(image_string)
    #resize accordingly
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [SCALE_SIZE, SCALE_SIZE])
    #convert label to one hot
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)
    return image, one_hot

def inference(image):
    #shape image for convolution
    with tf.name_scope('input_reshape'):
        x_image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, SCALE_SIZE, SCALE_SIZE, IMAGE_DEPTH]) #infer number of images, last dimension is features
        tf.summary.image('input_images',x_image)

    #neural net layers
    #100x100x3 -> 50x50x32
    h_pool1 = nnLayer.conv_layer(x_image, IMAGE_DEPTH, 5, 32, 'hiddenLayer1', act=tf.nn.relu)
    #50x50x32 -> 25x25x64
    h_pool2 = nnLayer.conv_layer(h_pool1, 32, 5, 64, 'hiddenLayer2', act=tf.nn.relu)
    #25x25x64 -> 1024x2
    h_fc1 = nnLayer.fc_layer(h_pool2, 64, 25, 1024, 'fcLayer1', act=tf.nn.relu)

    #1024x2 ->1x2
    with tf.name_scope('final-layer'):
        with tf.name_scope('weights'):
            W_fc2 = nnLayer.weight_variable([1024,NUM_CLASSES])
        with tf.name_scope('biases'):
            b_fc2 = nnLayer.bias_variable([NUM_CLASSES])

    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2

    return y_conv

def folderParser(folder):
    """output BMP file names in directory and
        label based on file name"""
    #create list of filenames in directory
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    #filter for BMP files
    bmpfiles = fnmatch.filter(files, '*.bmp')
    #create empty lists
    labels = []
    fullNames = []
    #get the length of the filename and determine left/right label
    for i in range(len(bmpfiles)):
        length = len(bmpfiles[i])
        fullNames.append(folder + '/'  + bmpfiles[i])
        if (bmpfiles[i][length-17])=='L':
            labels.append(1)
        else:
            labels.append(0)

    return fullNames,labels


def main(argv=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument

    #delete the log files if present
    #if tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.log_dir):
    #    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.log_dir)
    #tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.log_dir)

    #get file names and labels
    trainNames, trainLabels = folderParser(FLAGS.train_directory)
    testNames, testLabels = folderParser(FLAGS.test_directory)
    # create a dataset of the file names and labels
    tr_data = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainNames, trainLabels))
    ts_data = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testNames, testLabels))
    #map the data set from file names to images
    tr_data = tr_data.map(_parse_function)
    ts_data = ts_data.map(_parse_function)
    #shuffle the images
    tr_data = tr_data.shuffle(FLAGS.batch_size*2)
    ts_data = ts_data.shuffle(FLAGS.batch_size*2)
    #create batches
    tr_data = tr_data.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    ts_data = ts_data.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    #create handle for datasets
    handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
    iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, tr_data.output_types, tr_data.output_shapes)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    #setup iterator
    training_iterator = tr_data.make_initializable_iterator()
    validation_iterator = ts_data.make_initializable_iterator()
    #retrieve next batch
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    #run network
    y_conv = inference(features)
    #determine softmax and loss function
    with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
        diff = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=y_conv)
    with tf.name_scope('total'):
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(diff)
    tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy)
    #run gradient descent
    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        training_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cross_entropy)

    #identify correct predictions
    with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    #find the accuracy of the model
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #initialization of the variables
        training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
        validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        #merge all the summaries and write test summaries
        merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.log_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
        test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.log_dir + '/test')

        #run through epochs
        for epoch in range(FLAGS.num_epochs):
            #initialize the training set for training epoch
            sess.run(training_iterator.initializer)
            if epoch % 2 ==0:
                #initialize validation set
                sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
                #test
                summary, acc = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
                train_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch) #write to test file
                print('step %s, accuracy %s' % (epoch, acc))
            else:
                #train
                sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

    #close the log files
    train_writer.close()
    test_writer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Aaron

Comment: you may wanna check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585234/strange-values-of-training-and-testing-when-running-my-cnn-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment78174591_45585234

Comment: I was building the model with the old queue methods, but 1.3 recommends to switch over to the dataset methods.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was image standardization:

```
image_std = tf.image.per_image_standardization (image_resized)
```

Without the image standardization the neurons were becoming saturated. Improved the outcome straight away.

Thanks.